# Win10: Can't install unsigned drivers, even with testsigning on

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I've gone through all the steps shown in guides for installing unsigned drivers. I disabled secure boot, enabled test signing (I have the little watermark in the corner of the screen to prove it, plus here's what bcdedit has to say)

[image: output from bcdedit]

Yet when I try to install unsigned USB drivers for android fastboot, I still get:

```
Windows encountered a problem installing... the third-party INF does not contain digital signature information
```

Is there any further step?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what device's `fastboot` driver's aren't signed?  Most, if not all, major manufacturers sign their drivers.  As to your issue, have you verified Windows Defender, other anti-virus, or anti-malware software aren't preventing it?

Comment: YUREKA phone USB drivers. It's an absolute minefield trying to get hold of them in the first place; all hosted on dodgy malware-serving-just-add-this-plugin-to-chrome-to-download sites.

Comment: Have you searched on the [XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/yureka)?